# How to decode the UTF-8 response into text in JMeter

Tags: websocket, encoding, utf-8, jmeter, performance-testing

I have been trying to do performance testing in JMeter for websocket.

I have sent request data in Websocket request-response Sampler and received a UTF-8 encoded response.

I want to know a way to decode this response.

Request I sent
[Request Sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tctqx.png)

Response I received

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXZuS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's rather binary than UTF-8.

You can observe the bytes by using "Binary" format of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

If you want to compare it with anticipated - go for Binary Response Assertion:

[image]

More information:

- [WebSocket Samplers Documentation](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)
- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)